# Cant login to AWS EC2 instance with IGW/VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ec2

[Used this q's 2nd answer checklist](https://serverfault.com/questions/929024/do-you-need-or-you-dont-need-an-igw-to-get-access-to-the-internet-if-you-create)

Hello,
I am trying to login to an AWS Linux EC2 instance without much success.
I am doing this via cloudshell/android phablet.
The VPC has an IGW and a seeming correct route (0.0.0.0/0) attached.
There is an EIP available but since I wanted to change the key (to something generated inside powershell) I launched the instance as a clone with a public subnet/igw.
The SG and NACL have 443,80,22 ports open.
When I tried connecting to the public IP of the port, it hung.

Note: even using the *-i powershellkey* , *ssh* in cloudshell would not connect to the cloned instance which had only one ENI.

What do I do?

Comment: Try logging in using session manager. If that doesn't work I think we're going to need a more precise question with more information available to help you.

Comment: What happens when you try `telnet <EC2 IP> 22`? What INBOUND rules do the Security Groups that apply to the instance have?

Comment: Uberhumus, telnet and nc not available in cloudshell

Comment: Tim, I got the session manager to connect ( poorly: echo is slow) for a change. But docker0 has no carrier and no route to eip address.